# PDFs specific-to-content size audit

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I'd like to investigate on the relative *weight* of PDF documents content.
e.g. the PDF is 1MB, I want to see the percentage of size about included images, text, embedded fonts, etc.

i.e. I have an `.odt` document, that I used to export as PDF. I noticed that prior to an edit it was 80kB, after the edit the PDF grown to 200kb. The edit was merely cosmetic, I indented some part of the text. No text or even image addition!

Comment: Adobe Acrobat has an ["Audit Space Usage" feature](https://evermap.com/PDFFileSize.asp). Not sure if it runs on Linux, though.

Comment: @bariumbitmap, good! it looks like want I want. But currently I can't try it...

Comment: Adobe Acrobat hasn't supported linux since 2013